# How to get rid of space between html table?

Tags: html, html-table, space

How to get rid of these spaces between images? 
As you can see if I put images one after another there is no space and if I put below then there is a space. How do I resolve this?

[image: http://imgur.com/CqwN2Ve]

And here's the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<style type="text/css">
.table{
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing:0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table width="805" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table" align="center">
<tr>
<td><img src="sutent/1.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="sutent/2.png"><img src="sutent/3.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td1" ><img src="sutent/4a.jpg"><img src="sutent/5.png"><img src="sutent/8a.png"><img src="sutent/9a.png"><img src="sutent/13a.png"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="sutent/4b.png"><img src="sutent/6.png"><img src="sutent/8b.png"><img src="sutent/9b.png"><img src="sutent/13b.png"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to set 
       cellpadding:0;
       cellspacing:0;

In style

Comment: Can you provide a link to your website, or a jsFiddle replicating your problem.

Comment: @Zenith http://www.bmpadvertising.ro/test.html

Comment: @Zenith http://jsfiddle.net/qbHQD/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove `.` from the beginning of your declared class, and don't assign class to table

as

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing:0;
}
```

Comment: add `!important` to the style value as `border-collapse:collapse !important;` and add `padding:0 !important;` for `td` for `style` attribute.

Comment: `line-height:10px;` add this to `table` class which is defined before along with other properties.

Comment: @LuicanAdrian I would advise against using `line-height` to fix this. You should use `vertical-align:bottom` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type = "text/css">
tr
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
td
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
table
{
cellspacing:0;
cellpadding:0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: @LuicanAdrian also try removing the table class and calling it something else. Maybe the is confliction between the class and the tag name.

Comment: i did it , but still have space between cells

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd throw in my input in case it helps someone. Sometimes I run into issues with the font-size or line-height being to big - they can create spaces between table cells even if there is no text. Maybe you ought to look into that.

Comment: @DrewNusser: that's good advice, can you elaborate on a solution should this indeed be the case?

Comment: @HashemQolami; if you read the answer carefully you'll notice that he is actually suggesting a possible cause of this problem.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You're absolutely right. Sorry, my bad.

Comment: So, if it is the case that it's the line-height or font-size messing with your tables, you would just need to shrink them down to fit inside the cell. I believe the default line-height is around 1.2em, so you could try going down to 1.1, or just decreasing the font-size in that cell.